# How many moons does Gallifrey have?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who the Doctor's home world is in a binary star system. It is also several times larger than Earth and must have a great gravitational pull.

My question is, has there ever been mention of how many moons it has?

Comment: I do not understand the down vote.

Comment: @Lexible I downvoted because it took about 2 seconds to find the answer

Comment: @calccrypto - Ah, but the answer is far more interesting than just "two". There are canon contradictions to explore :-)

Answer (score 7):

### Two, or one, or none.

Depending on your preferred reference materials, Gallifrey either has one natural satellite (known as [**Pazithi Gallifreya**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Pazithi_Gallifreya)) or two or possibly none. The planet also has a wide variety of artifical orbital structures visible from the surface and a dust ring system similar to that of Saturn.

From the Prose novel [Cat's Cradle : Time's Crucible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat's_Cradle:_Time's_Crucible) :

> Pazithi the mystic, the virgin moon Goddess, still watched over them,
>   and was still worshipped. Yet even with the antique telescope at his
>   window, he could make out the industrial complexes that fouled her
>   sacred surface with angled shadow — the dust-grubbers and smelting
>   furnaces that raped her divine celestial beauty.

From the Prose novel [Lungbarrow](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Lungbarrow_(novel)) :

> 'It's a coincidence. A downfall of fish, frogs or water lilies can be
>   precipitated by any simple tornado. Have they forgotten about ocean
>   cones, when the Gallifreyan sea gets sucked miles high by an eclipse
>   of the sun and the dark moon?

The Doctor Who comic [Agent Provocateur](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Agent_Provocateur) shows Pazithi Gallifreya but it also shows **another large green-coloured moon in opposition**.

[image]

The prose novel [The Gallifrey Chronicles](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Gallifrey_Chronicles_(novel)) records that Pazithi was destroyed in the final stages of the Time War, along with the (apparent) destruction of Gallifrey. It fails to mention any other moons:

> The ivory moon, Pazithi Gallifreya, was caught and consumed by one of
>   the atmospheric flares

To add further confusion, on both occasions that we see Gallifrey from space in the TV series (Day of the Doctor, End of Time Pt II), on neither occasion does it appear to have any moons at all.

[image]

And in the Doctor's reminiscence in "The Sound of Drums", we only see one satellite, presumably Pazithi.

[image]

Comment: What! There is some historical reference to a green moon that was not specifically stated to be destroyed while the other one was. Looks like we found next season's finale.

Answer (score 6):

In the [Tardis Data Core](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gallifrey), it says that there **were** at least 2 moons. Specifically:

> SATELLITES
>
> Gallifrey had at least two large moons and a ring system,
>   similar to Saturn in Earth's solar system. (COMIC: Agent Provocateur)
>   One of the moons was the copper-coloured [Pazithi Gallifreya](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Pazithi_Gallifreya), which
>   shone so brightly it could be seen during the day. (PROSE: Cat's
>   Cradle: Time's Crucible, Lungbarrow) Gallifrey's moons perished with
>   the Daleks when Gallifrey disappeared. (COMIC: Agent Provocateur, TV:
>   The Day of the Doctor)

Comment: The sole mention of a second moon is in the comic. This contradicts the prose novels and the TV series where we only see one large moon.

Comment: @Richard Doctor Who cannon? Whoa there

Comment: Canon inconsistencies in Doctor Who? Whoever heard of such a thing? Madness, I tells ya.